If you are trying to get the task api/endpoint for clickup tasks and not getting
If  you are through https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/list/${listId}/task you will get task but wont get the completed task
I have tried that api but not getting the completed task only getting the in progress and todo tasks so I have tried various times but not get the expected results

As I have post this question  you are through https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/list/${listId}/task you will get task but wont get it
But if you add the query on last to include the closed task like
https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/list/${listId}/task?include_closed-true
Then you will get your all tasks including your completed task
If you find this helpful then Plzz let me know
